# Hibernate & Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I'm having trouble running a sample hibernate app on tomcat 7 + eclipse.  The app I'm running is the one provided at hibernate.org with minor changes to test the set up.

When I attempt to access the session object the server throws an exception.  I did a plug-in search on the IDE and could not find the org.hibernate.session package in the hibernate3.jar file located in my src/lib.  However, eclipsed allowed the import without any error warnings..

Stack trace:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class core.EmployeeManager
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.16 logs.
```

Thank you,
Nguyen

Answer (score 4):

Don't put that in `src/lib`; all your 3rd party JARs belong in the `WEB-INF/lib` of your deployed WAR file.

This means you should ask Eclipse to create a WAR file for you (can be exploded) and deploy that to Tomcat.

Comment: I would say Maven today as well.